# Service to call REST endpoint on schedule, parse json reply and perform conditional action

Tags: web-services, workflow, saas

I have a requirement to

1. Call a particular API (via REST endpoint) including date in query
   string and auth in headers. *(This API is an internal app and won't be in any integration directory)*
2. Retrieve results in JSON format.
3. Parse results and look for simple conditions (e.g. something like
   data.Errors > 10)
4. If condition met perform another action (in this case sending an email of the results).

Obviously I could do this using a simple program or using script/curl/cron but I am wondering if there is a modern SaaS type app that can do this?

- IFTTT can't call arbitary REST API's as far as I am aware.
- Unsure about Zapier?
- Microsoft Flow?
- Any others?

Comment: Got something running with Zapier but its a little limited for 'power use' - e.g. the GET step doesn't seem to allow you to work with JSON arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to complete these exact steps using Microsoft Flow.

1. Set a Recurrence task in Microsoft Flow to run the flow on a schedule
2. Call a particular API (via REST endpoint) using an HTTP Action
3. Retrieve the JSON results. Add a condition to check for a Status Code of 200
4. If Yes, send relevant individuals an email when the REST call is successful

There are actions in Microsoft Flow to parse the JSON data as well.